# Copy-Paste Efficiency and an Array of Worksheets in VBA

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, vba

I have the following code for pasting a certain range of cells in an array of worksheets - not all of them:

```
dim ws as Worksheet
dim DecisionWorksheets
dim myPassword as String
dim copyrange
dim wf as WorksheetFunction

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set DecisionWorksheets = Sheets(Array("ADMIN", "LM", "CA", "FM", "GD"))
For Each ws In DecisionWorksheets
    ws.Unprotect myPassword
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
Next ws

rownum = wf.Max(Range("B:B"))
copyrange = Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(rownum + 3, 6)).Copy

For Each ws In DecisionWorksheets
    ws.Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next ws

For Each ws In DecisionWorksheets
    ws.Protect myPassword
Next ws
```

Each of the worksheets in an array above is password protected and if I put "ws.Unprotect myPassword" inside my second loop, the cut-copy mode is disabled. Because of this, I created a separate "for each" loop, which would first go through an array of worksheets to unprotect them (1st loop) and then to protect them back again (3rd loop).

My question is about the efficiency of my code. Namely, I am just wondering whether there is any way I could unite these three loops into a single one.
Any other suggestions would also be very appreciated!

Comment: @Davesexcel , I considered the copy code to be not that important, that is why I decided to omit that. Nevertheless, I edited my code - now, it has the copy code. As for another question on your part, the range being copied is located on an unprotected sheet.

Comment: @Davesexcel ,This code is way too long for me to show all of it. I missed the definition of that "wf" in my code, sorry for that. It is a WorksheetFunction (I have editied my code for that). As for the general description of that portion of the code, the "B" column has a sequence of numbers from 1 to N,which appear as some data is entered in columns "C" to "F" on a sheet. For example,if I enter two rows of some information, the "B" column will have number "1" in cell "B4" and "2" in cell "B5". Hence, this portion of the code will make the copy range go down by one row from "B4" ("cells(4,2)").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the paste code did not originally work for you because you were clearing the worksheet cells in your loop that canceled the copy mode.
If you copy a range then go to another sheet and delete cells, you no longer have those cells copied.
You may have to copy and paste after you clear the cells. Look at this example.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim DecisionWorksheets
    Dim myPassword As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet, LstRw As Long, CopyRng As Range

    myPassword = "123"
    Set DecisionWorksheets = Sheets(Array("ADMIN", "LM", "CA", "FM", "GD"))

    Set sh = Sheets("Data")

    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set CopyRng = .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(LstRw + 3, 6))
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    For Each ws In DecisionWorksheets
        ws.Unprotect myPassword
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
        CopyRng.Copy
        ws.Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ws.Protect myPassword
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your code! Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that CopyRng.Copy inside your loop copies the range from each sheet in an array. Perhaps, I did not specify it explicitly that I copy the data from one sheet only (this is given in the copy code I specified, though) and then copy that very range into each sheet within the array.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. CopyRng is only from Data sheet.